# TestNG -Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, intellij-13

I am using `Testng`, I have two classes `Util and test1`.

I have 4 simple test methods in `Test1` class printing just the name of method. On running the `testng.xml`, it prints the expected statements from each method for a sec and then replaces it with error - Process finished with exit code 0. I am using `Intellij IDE`.
Could anyone suggest anything on this.

**Code :**

```
class util {....}
class tets1 {
@Test
public void testmethod2(){
System.out.println("In testmethod2");
}

@Test
public void testmethod3(){
System.out.println("In testmetho3");
}

 @Test
 public void testmethod4()
 {
 System.out.println("In testmethod4");
 }

 @Test
 public void testmethod5(){
 System.out.println("In testmetho5");
 }
```

**Testng.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1">
<test name="test1">
<classes>
<class name="TagPackage.Test1"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an error, this is the correct behaviour in IntelliJ.

The console is displaying the output of each test as it goes, the message `Process finished with exit code 0` states that the test run was successful.  If a test fails this will say something else (for Spock this returns 255).

If you look to the left of the console you should see the tests that were executed, or clicking on the test name at the top of the tree you will see all of the console output.

Comment: For me, the variation between results is that some times part or all of the System.out.println cmds are not showing a result in the Run Console.  But thank you for explaining the message is not an ERR

Comment: You haven't got an accidental `System.exit()` in your code do you?